# Authenticating an express app with Passport - Expressjs Passportjs

Tags: javascript, session, express, passport.js

I have an `express` app that I am trying to authenticate with `passport-local`.  Here is my `express` app:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'this is a string' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect();

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    var query = client.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE EMAIL = $1', [username], function(err, result){
      if(err) {
        console.log("Error");
        return done(err);
      }
      if(!result.rows.length > 0) {
        console.log("No users");
        return done(null, false, { message: 'User not found'});
      }
      if(result.rows[0].password !== password) {
        console.log("incorrect password");
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Password Incorrect'});
      }
      console.log('authenticated');
      return done(null, result.rows[0]);
    });
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  'use strict';
  console.log('serialize');
  console.log(user);
  done(null, user.email);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  'use strict';
  console.log('deserialize');
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
  'use strict';
  console.log(req.user.username);
});

app.listen(port, function() {
  'use strict';
  console.log('Listening on:', port);
});
```

I then hit the `/login` url with this `json` in my body: `{username: 'jason@gmail.com', password: 'password` }.  I go through the `LocalStrategy` function and then in the serialize function it makes it to the `done` function and then just hangs.  I get no errors or additional logging, the connection just stays open and control is not given back to the caller.  I never receive a `http` status, it just hangs.

I think it is a problem with my `session`, but I do not understand what to do next?

Comment: Short question. Do you get an output at console.log(req.user.username); when open yourDomain:port/login ?

Comment: I changed it to `console.log(req.user.user_name)` and then I get the user name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, could you try a redirect there? It looks like your session / auth is ok, if you get a proper username at that point.

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { 
  successRedirect: '/somewhere_intern', 
  failureRedirect: '/login' 
}));
```

Comment: I added `{ successRedirect: "/users", failureRedirect: "/projects" }` The error I then get is `Cannot GET /users`.

Comment: I didnt have the `/users` route defined in this file.